# Compiling magick++ stuff in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, imagemagick, codeblocks, magick++

I'm doing some experimenting with magick++ and when I compile my snippets I just use g++ and type `` g++ test.cpp `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs` -o prog `` but I have recently fallen in love Code:Blocks and I'm wondering how I can tell it to compile like above? I haven't been able to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Open from menu →Project →Build Options 
Navigate to →Compiler settings →OtherOptions and enter:

```
$\(Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags\)
```

Navigate to →Linker settings and enter to →Other linker options:

```
$\(Magick++-config --ldflags --libs\)
```

Escaping `\(` and `\)` are necessary.
Remember to select the project on left, not a build target.